# How can I align span and img elements along the same line?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to design the following:

[image]

```html
<div>
    <div style="width: 45%; text-overflow: ellipsis; white-space: nowrap; overflow:hidden;">
        <img src="/assets/images/file@2x.png">
        <span>eb 3p_2D(V1)</span>
    </div>
    <span style="width: 10%">2019-08-08</span>
    <span style="width: 10%">94.41 KB</span>
    <img src="/assets/images/file@2x.png" style="cursor: pointer; color: #237ae4; font-size: 24px;">
</div>
```

This does not give me what I am looking for. My code makes the following and not responsive:

[image]

How can I make this look like the one in the image?

**UPDATE**

In mobile, this is how I want the UI to be
[image]

Comment: i think you have to use bootstrap

Comment: He doesn't HAVE to, but it could be a nice way to start with responsive HTML for a beginner. See the boostrap doc here : https://getbootstrap.com/

Comment: What problem are you having with it?  Is it not all in a line like you wanted? please be a little more specific.

Comment: @Jonny: Please check my update

Comment: I am just guessing that your problem is that the text goes below. if that's it then it's the `div` will automatically make a line-break

Comment: @PeakGen add `white-space: nowrap;` in `.parent` in CSS

Comment: you can use `flexbox` css or `grid layout`

Comment: Please stick to comments below answers to describe how a solution might fall short -- don't update your question each time you've tried an unsuccessful answer. That leads to confusion as to what your problem really is and gives the appearance of invalidating other existing answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox) to easily align elements on the Y or X axis.

Use `display: flex, justify-content: space-between` on your parent element to align everything the way it is in your example. I also advice to give your date and filesize spans a little more `width` so the text doesn't wrap.

You can also give the date and filesize spans a `min-width` to make sure they always have enough space to render their content.

You could also wrap your spans in a div and use `flexbox` to properly wrap your spans below eachother on smaller screens.

---

You now have a **parent** with 3 elements `img`, `div` and `img`.

`justify-content` and `align-items` will make sure these 3 elements are centered on both axises.

Your **div** with classname `spans` also has 3 elements, 3 `spans`.

`justify-content` will make sure these 3 elements are spaced evenly on their main axis. *(based on the available space between those 3 elements.)*
`flex-wrap` will wrap those elements below eachother when their isn't enough place to render them next to eachother.

See below snippets for a working example.

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
 
  border: 1px solid rgb(220, 220, 220);
  padding: 10px;
}

.image {
  width: 45%;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.span {
  width: 20%;
  min-width: 90px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.spans {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div>
    <img src="/assets/images/file@2x.png"/>
  </div>
  <div class="spans">
    <span class="image">eb 3p_2D(V1)</span>
    <span class="span">2019-08-08</span>
    <span class="span">94.41 KB</span>
  </div>
  <img src="/assets/images/file@2x.png" style="cursor: pointer; color: #237ae4; font-size: 24px;"/>

</div>
```

Comment: Your answer works great, except for mobile, please check my updated question

Comment: How exactly would you like your element to look on mobile? I have updated my answer to show a simple solution which could solve your problem with the mobile version.

Comment: Please check the updated question. I have posted an image of what I want

Comment: You can also just let me know how I can get the updated UI, no need to worry about the desktop look and feel. I am going to use your already submitted UI for the desktop and hide that element in mobile. I will use a mobile specific one for mobile versions.

Comment: There is no need for a separate element in mobile. You can use `flexbox` again to properly wrap your spans below eachother when the screen is too small for them to be next to eachother. I have edited my answer to reflect those changes.

Answer (score 0):

You can include elements inside the `<div>`

Your code:

```
<div>
    <div style="width: 45%; text-overflow: ellipsis; white-space: nowrap; overflow:hidden;">
        <img src="/assets/images/file@2x.png">
            <span>eb 3p_2D(V1)</span>
        </div>
        <span style="width: 10%">2019-08-08</span>
        <span style="width: 10%">94.41 KB</span>
        <img src="/assets/images/file@2x.png" style="cursor: pointer; color: #237ae4; font-size: 24px;">

    </div>
```

Sample Solution:

```
<div>
    <div style="width: 45%; text-overflow: ellipsis; white-space: nowrap; overflow:hidden;">
        <img src="/assets/images/file@2x.png">
            <span>eb 3p_2D(V1)</span>
        <span style="width: 10%">2019-08-08</span>
        <span style="width: 10%">94.41 KB</span>
        <img src="/assets/images/file@2x.png" style="cursor: pointer; color: #237ae4; font-size: 24px;">
        </div>
    </div>
```

Just tell me if you want something specific

Answer (score 0):

I added flex on 2 elements to align the elements and keep them centered a float to keep them in order.  I also placed a little padding on the elements and a border.

```html
<div style="border:thin #cccccc solid; padding:3px; width:100%; float:left; display:flex; justify-content: space-between; align-items:center;">
   
   <div style="width:43%;text-overflow: ellipsis; white-space: nowrap; overflow:hidden; padding-left:3px; display:flex;  align-items:center;">
        <img style="float:left;" src="/assets/images/file@2x.png">
            <span style="float:left; margin-left:10%;">eb 3p_2D(V1)</span>
        </div>
        
        <span style="float:left; width: 10%;">2019-08-08</span>
        <span style="float:left; width: 13%;">94.41 KB</span>
        <img src="/assets/images/file@2x.png" style="cursor: pointer; color: #237ae4; font-size: 24px; float:right;  padding-right:3px;">

    </div>
```